# How to get data from nested json using oracle apex

Tags: javascript, sql, json, oracle, oracle-apex

I am not able to get data from nested array of json in oracle apex.

```
{
    "payload": [
        {
            "itemId": "155364958",
            "title": "N1000001",
            "terms": [
                {
                    "title": "Price",
                    "fieldId": "PRICE",
                    "valueTypeName": "Money",
                    "isMultiValue": false,
                    "acceptableValues": "LimitedRange",
                    "isRequirement": false
                    
                }]
        }] }
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include: **your** attempt at a solution; the issues/errors with **your** solution; and the output you are expecting.

Comment: it's not clear if you want to do that in the app/browser via JavaScript, or with SQL - which I would think it more appropriate. see MTO's answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i want to achieve this using oracle apex and plsql in oracle apex.

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON_TABLE` with `NESTED PATH`:

```sql
SELECT j.*
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         t.value,
         '$.payload[*]'
         COLUMNS (
           itemId VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.itemId',
           title  VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.title',
           NESTED PATH '$.terms[*]' COLUMNS(
             term_title        VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.title',
             field_id          VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.fieldId',
             value_type_name   VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.valueTypeName',
             is_multi_value    VARCHAR2(5)  PATH '$.isMultiValue',
             acceptable_values VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.acceptableValues',
             is_requirement    VARCHAR2(5)  PATH '$.isRequirement'
           )
         )
       ) j
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (value JSON);

INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (
'{
    "payload": [
        {
            "itemId": "155364958",
            "title": "N1000001",
            "terms": [
                {
                    "title": "Price",
                    "fieldId": "PRICE",
                    "valueTypeName": "Money",
                    "isMultiValue": false,
                    "acceptableValues": "LimitedRange",
                    "isRequirement": false
                    
                }
            ]
        }
  ]
}');
```

Outputs:

| ITEMID | TITLE | TERM_TITLE | FIELD_ID | VALUE_TYPE_NAME | IS_MULTI_VALUE | ACCEPTABLE_VALUES | IS_REQUIREMENT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 155364958 | N1000001 | Price | PRICE | Money | false | LimitedRange | false |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xxq12DMt)

Comment: Hi i used the sql query which you have provided to create json table but it throws error, Error at line 1/32: ORA-00902: invalid datatype
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_220200", line 828
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_220200", line 813
ORA-06512: at "APEX_220200.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 2046


1. CREATE TABLE table_name (value JSON);

Comment: @Programmingwithsaadmalik Then use `CLOB` or `VARCHAR2(4000)` instead. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hGdyhFWS)

Comment: @fiddle can you elaborate more on clob? As what the whole code will look like using clob?

Comment: @fiddle i have done as you have said & its workings, thanks bro, just want to confirm one thing more, can we use nested array in this way also? as if we have an other array in the terms then using same pattern we can call nested array? or how can we call an other array in the array terms?

Comment: @Programmingwithsaadmalik Ask another question and include a [MRE] with the additional arrays because it is not clear what you are asking or what output you expect and this is not something that can be answered easily in comments. (And is outside the scope of this question.)